# Use the between function in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

How do you use the "between" function on phpMyAdmin search function?

[image]

I've tried

```
 2012-11-29 AND 2012-11-30
```

and

```
 '2012-11-29' AND '2012-11-30'
```

and when I press "go" it returns back to this screen. There are definetly results, because if I set the date to = `2012-11-29` I get a result.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, for normal fields you should use comma to separate values. For example, to include `BETWEEN 4 AND 5` clause in your query, just write `4, 5` in that input. In your case entering `2012-11-29, 2012-11-30` should do the trick.

Interestingly, the current version of `phpMyAdmin` (3.5.1) just doesn't let comma into a datetime column-related input.

Comment: Yeah, and in the 4.0.4.1, still doesn't.

Comment: 3.5.8.2 doesn't let me input anything except date string, not even quotes

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `,` between dates, since the file doesn't let you to enter non-numerical characters, so you can copy `,` from somewhere else and paste it PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Really helpful!